# How to retrieve string from a 2 dimensional array

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def foo(val)
{
  one: [["one1", "1"]],
  two: [
         ["two1", "1"],
         ["two2", "2"]],
}[val]
end
```

I want to retrieve "two1" from "1", how do I do that?

Note: I want to do [:two]["1"]

Comment: You only want the first ony of the two results you get with :two ?

Comment: What do you mean by `val="two" and "1"`?

Comment: Exactly what I meant, I am passing two arguments (i.e. "two", "1" OR "one", "1")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def foo(v1, v2)
  hsh = {
    'one' => [["one1", "1"]],
    'two' => [ ["two1", "1"],
         ["two2", "2"] ],
  }
  hsh[v1].select{|i| i[0] == (v1 + v2) && v2 == i[1] }.first.first
end
```